# "Es gibt kein Dazwischen" — groß oder klein?

Tags: capitalization

Mein Gefühl sagt groß - aber gibt es Regeln für solche schrägen Fälle? Wenn man so ein Wort substantiviert, müsste es ja eigentlich großgeschrieben werden. Es geht um so einen "Joda"-Kontext:

> "Tu es oder tu es nicht - es gibt kein Dazwischen."

Comment: Substantivierungen werden **immer** groß geschrieben. Und dieser Fall ist nicht schräger als andere Fälle; *alle* Substantivierungen betreffen Worte anderer Klassen. Ein Pronominaladverb groß zu schreiben, ist nicht ungewöhnlicher, als ein Verb groß zu schreiben.

Comment: @KilianFoth: Wenn alle Fälle gleich schräg wären, solange sie grammatikalisch korrekt sind, wäre Schreiben ganz schön langweilig...

Comment: ...auch wenn ich verstehe, wie es gemeint war.

Comment: Einfach ein bisschen schwanger sein – Problem gelöst ;)

Comment: Ein bisschen schwanger sein...??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Die deutsche Rechtschreibung fordert für alles, was als Substantiv genutzt wird, die Großschreibung.

Dazu gehören Verbformen (meistens Partizipformen und Infinitive), Adjektive, und natürlich auch Präpositionen, die als Substantiv genutzt werden. Und Worte, von denen ich nicht mal die Wortart kenne - Die ursprüngliche Wortart ist dafür egal.

> Das Für und Wider abwägen
>
> Sich über das ständige Hin und Her aufregen
>
> Das Abwägen des Für und Wider
>
> Aus dem Publikum kamen Ahs und Ohs.

Oft sieht man sogar Substantivierungen, wenn es eigentlich ein passendes Substantiv gibt:

> Die Leere zwischen den Planeten

vs.

> Das Leere zwischen den Welten

(An diesem Beispiel sieht man auch schön, dass Substantivierungen gefälligst ein Neutrum zu sein haben)

In deinem Beispiel ist die Verwendung von *dazwischen* als Substantiv ziemlich eindeutig - Schliesslich kann man einen Artikel annehmen oder den Satz negieren ("es gibt *ein* Dazwischen"), so dass ein Artikel verwendet wird (Das mache ich nur deswegen, weil strittig sein könnte, ob "kein" ein Artikel ist).

Substantivierung erkennt man u.A. an einem vorgestellten Artikel, einem zugeordneten Adjektiv, oder einem Pronomen (z.B. "kein"). In anderen Beispielen könnte der Nachweis der (Nicht-)Substantivierung ein bißchen komplizierter sein:

> Du bist nicht von gestern, sondern von vorgestern

vs.

> Gruß aus dem Gestern

Noch ein bisschen komplexer wird es bei mehrteiligen Präpositionen: Schreibt man jetzt

> Das Weder Noch?

oder besser

> Hier kam ein klares Als ob als Antwort?

Duden meint dazu, solche Substantivierungen mehrteiliger Präpositionen sollten groß geschrieben und mit einem Bindestrich verbunden werden

> Ein unbedingtes Entweder-oder

(Nur weil das so schön zu deinem Joda-Beispiel passt...)

Comment: Perfekt, so dachte ich mir das auch... Schräg ist es trotzdem, solche Wörter zu substantivieren. (Deshalb mache ich es ja auch...)